# Is there a filter available to Format an item price to include a comma in django?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

For example:

10283 → should become 10,283.00
2938449 → should become 2,938,449.00
Is there a way to do such format, or is it something can’t be achieved with current django string and float format functions?

Comment: if you are representing currency try https://pypi.org/project/money/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its something built into python!

you use the format method on the string class like this

```
In : "{:,}".format(100000.123)
Out: '100,000.123'
```

It can do lots of things, like limit decimals like this:

```
In : "{:,.2f}".format(100000.123)
Out: '100,000.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `format()` function to format the numbers as you like either integers or floats, add commas or make the frictions down to just two.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily find this lifetime with the (intcomma) filter

To use this filter, you must first add << django.contrib.humanize >> to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file.

settings.py file:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
# ...
'django.contrib.humanize',
# ...
```

]

Then use the intcomma filter in your template:

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ android.price|intcomma:False }}
```